# What is the correct way to reference self objects

Tags: python

I'm creating an instance called Dog1. I'm curious what's the best practice in referencing objects.
Would I refer them later on in the class by self.breed or just by the object name breed.
For example in the print function below would I put in `print(f"My name's {self.name})` or `print(f"My name's {name})`

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self, name, age, breed):
        self.name = name 
        self.age = age
        self.breed = breed

        print(f"My name's {name}")
```

Comment: `would I put...` - did you try either of those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In later functions, you would refer to your variables as `self.name`. For example, you could do this:

```py
class Dog:
    def __init__(self, name, age, breed):
        self.name = name 
        self.age = age
        self.breed = breed

        print(f"My name's {self.name}")

    def print_breed(self):
        print(f"I'm a {self.breed}")

dog = Dog("Fido", 10, "spaniel")  # >>> My name's Fido
dog.print_breed()  # >>> I'm a spaniel
```

Here, when you call `dog.print_breed()`, where `dog` is a variable instance of the Dog class, you would get back what the dog's breed is.

Comment: Just a note: you do not need the function `def breed` as you can just reference the dog's breed via `dog.breed`.

Comment: @Felipe In fact, this doesn't work because `self.breed = breed` overrides the `breed()` method. Don't do this. Maybe it was supposed to be a [property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) instead, although where it doesn't do anything extra, it would only make sense as an example.

Comment: I edited the code to actually run, and hopefully make a bit more practical sense too.

Comment: @wjandrea Indeed. I left the original answer by M-Chen-3 without any modification- only styling. Then left a comment to indicate the function is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self, name, age, breed):
        self.name = name + '-sss-'
        self.age = age
        self.breed = breed

        print(f"My name's {name}")
        print(f"My name's {self.name}")
    def s(self):
        print(self.name)
        try:
            print(name)
        except NameError as e:
            print(e)
```

It depends on what you want. Within the `__init__` method `{name}` will print the value you passed for that argument. `{self.name`} will print the instance attribute.

```
In [10]: d = Dog('foo',1,2)
My name's foo
My name's foo-sss-
```

In instance methods you need to use self.

```
In [11]: d.s()
foo-sss-
name 'name' is not defined
```

Comment: I read this a few times over and it makes sense. If you call it without the self it just reference the value as you mentioned and not the whole thing

Comment: if there was an addition on top of that as you said

Comment: @Continuit [9.1 and 9.2 in the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-word-about-names-and-objects) are good reads (a must?) as well as [Naming and binding](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html) in the Language reference.